# ¿Como puedo subir datos desde un archivo plano(excel) a SQL server express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, insert, migration

He intentado subir un archivo plano(excel) en formatos xlsx y csv pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Mens. 4864, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1 Error de conversión de datos
>   de carga masiva (tipo no coincidente o carácter no válido para la
>   página de códigos especificada) en la fila 1, columna 1 (IdFactura).

El id de factura esta bien ya que es un campo numérico que comienza desde el 2 ya que hay un dato registrado.

Ya realice una prueba en un tipo de archivo txt y funciono perfectamente pero todos los datos están es en  excel que puedo hacer en ese caso.

Tambien lo intente por medio de la herramienta de asistencia de sql server pero no me permitió subirlo.

```
BULK

INSERT factura
FROM 'D:\Datos\DatosE.csv'
WITH

( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' ) 

GO
```

esta es la tabla correspondiente

```
 create table factura(

 IdFactura int not null PRIMARY KEY,
 NumeroFactura varchar(30) not null,
 CedulaCliente varchar(15) not null,
 Direccion varchar(20) not null,
 Direccion2 varchar(20) not null,
 Departamento varchar(20),
 Ciudad varchar(20),
 Barrio varchar(20),
 Subtotal numeric(10,2) not null,
 iva numeric(10,2) not null,
 CargoExtras numeric(10,2) not null,
 Total numeric(10,2) not null,
 fecha date,
 ClienteID int,
 PedidoID int,

 );
```

y a continuación un ejemplo de los datos a pasar

```
       3,   125,    87654321,   cra 24 # 34 13, 0,  bolivar,    cartagena,  
       San_Antonio, 1008403.36, 191596.64,  50000,  1250000,    2017-05-02, 2,  3
```

Comment: lo tengo en estos dos formatos csv y xlsx, los datos son :                                      3 125 87654321 cra 24 # 34 13 0 bolivar cartagena San_Antonio 1008403.36 191596.64 50000 1250000 2017-05-02 2 3

Comment: el error lo tira cuando intento subir o csv o xlsx, y si el orden de los datos es correcto

Comment: create table factura(

IdFactura int not null PRIMARY KEY,
NumeroFactura varchar(30) not null,
CedulaCliente varchar(15) not null,
Direccion varchar(20) not null,
Direccion2 varchar(20) not null,
Departamento varchar(20),
Ciudad varchar(20),
Barrio varchar(20),
Subtotal numeric(10,2) not null,
iva numeric(10,2) not null,
CargoExtras numeric(10,2) not null,
Total numeric(10,2) not null,
fecha date,
ClienteID int,
PedidoID int,
 
 );

Comment: subí la tabla que no era lo siento, arriba esta la tabla correspondiente

Comment: 3, 125, 87654321, cra 24 # 34 13, 0, bolivar, cartagena, San_Antonio, 1008403.36, 191596.64, 50000, 1250000, 2017-05-02,  2,  3  los separe por comas espero se entienda mejor.

Comment: Prueba quitar la fila del encabezado al CSV si lo tiene o hacer un BULK con el parámetro `FIRSTROW = 2`

Comment: no tiene encabezado y le puse el parámetro y no sale el error pero tampoco inserta los datos         sale el mensaje (0 filas afectadas)

Comment: Intenta utilizando decimal(10,18) en lugar de numeric(10,2) o verifica que el valor 1008403.36 sea con comas. Ademas, cambia Direccion varchar(20) not null, por nvarchar